# Not Updating amChart with Observable data stream when onClick event fires

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, amcharts

Can someone who understands rxjs's Observable type help me understand what I'm doing wrong here? The amChart4's radar chart I'm using is passed a data source property that is correctly reflecting data from index[0] of the original data structure (as shown in the radar chart image), but when I try to update this data source (data stream) property the chart is not reflecting the new index in the array or data values passed into the data source/stream.

I'll try to provide as much genericized data as possible to help anyone identify and teach me on what I'm doing wrong here. If you need more code or info, let me know.

**Intended effect:** when this refresh button is clicked on in this table shown below, I want to update the values on a chart in another tab.

**Actual effect:** when button is clicked, browser console reports the message from the reportItemClick() function. However, the chart is not updating the `this.currentMeterRead$: Observable<AngleRead[]>` property.

**Note: in case you are wondering why does the currentMeterRead$ property accept an AngleRead[] instead of a AngleRead object, when the chart is only displaying a single AngleRead instance of data; amCharts RadarChart this.chart.data property must accept an array in order to populate the chart.*
[image: table showing onClick button]
[image]

In main.component.html

```html
<div class="plot"><phase-angle-radar-chart [source]="currentMeterRead$"></phase-angle-radar-chart></div>
```

In main.component.ts

```js
public currentMeterRead$: Observable<AngleRead[]>;
public originalData: AngleRead[];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.entityCardService.getPhaseAnglePlotDataApi(this.options).subscribe((data: OperationResult<PhaseAnglePlotCard>) => {
        this.originalData = _.cloneDeep(data.result.angleReads);
        this.currentMeterRead$ = of([this.originalData[this.meterReadIndex = 0]]);
    }
}

public reportItemClick(element: AngleRead) {
        console.log("Refresh button clicked...\n")
        console.log(element);
        console.log([this.originalData.find(read => read == element)]);
        this.currentMeterRead$ = of([this.originalData.find(read => read == element)]);
        console.log("End");
}
```

In chart.component.ts

```js
export class PhaseAngleRadarChartComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() public set source(data: Observable<AngleRead[]>) {
        // an AngleRead object with all 0 or null default values, helps draw the line in the radar chart. Data intentionally left out for stackoverflow to make example more concise.
        const dummyData = [];

        this.sourceSubscription.unsubscribe();
        if (isObservable(data)) {
            this.sourceSubscription = data.subscribe((read) => {
                //var test: AngleRead[] = [...read, ...dummyData];
                this._source.next([...read, ...dummyData]);
            });
            
        }
        else {
            this.loggerService.warn(`Radar Chart data source must be set to an observable. Chart won't show any data otherwise.`);
            this._source.next([]);
        }
    }

    private chart: any;
    private dummyData: AngleRead[];
    private sourceSubscription: Subscription;
    private _source: BehaviorSubject<AngleRead[]>;
    private subscriptions: Subscription[];

    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId, private zone: NgZone, private loggerService: LoggerService) {
        this._source = new BehaviorSubject([]);
        this.subscriptions = [];
        this.sourceSubscription = Subscription.EMPTY;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.browserOnly(() => {
            // rest of chart code removed for conciseness in example...
            this.chart.data = this._source.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside my personal dislike of mixing `subscribe()` with observables, lodash, deepCopy and unsubscribed subscriptions... Anyway, is it a requiremt to pass an observable to the other chart? Why not just send the data via `@Input`?

If you've already set up observable `this.currentMeterRead$` for the `PhaseAngleRadarChartComponent` shouldn't `reportItemClick()` just next the observable forward to the chart? E.g

```js
public reportItemClick(element: AngleRead) {
        console.log("Refresh button clicked...\n")
        console.log(element);
        console.log([this.originalData.find(read => read == element)]);
        this.currentMeterRead$ = of([this.originalData.find(read => read == element)]);
        this.currentMeterRead$.next(); // <---
        console.log("End");
}
```

Also now test if `@Input() public set source` is updated on `reportItemClick()`